# How to make react rerender after each one of multiple setStates in one function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to add "loading" functionality to my component.
The problem is that loading isn't async function,
so setStates are probably batching themselves.
Let's take a look at the code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        loading: false,
        myArray: [1,2,3, ... ,500] //pseudo code (i want to say there is 500 elements, not exactly numbers (cuz i have objects) but to illustrate the problem it doesn't matter)
    };
}

editTable = (howManyElementsToEdit) => {
    if(howManyElementsToEdit > 50) {

        // set loading to true (and make react rerender)
        this.setState({
            loading: true,
        })

        //after react rerendering (the react knows that is in this specified line number in this method?) i want to do the calculations

        const tmp = [...this.state.myArray]; //copy the array
        for(let i=0; i<howManyElementsToEdit; i++) {
            tmp[i] += 1;
        }

        //and now after the modification is done, setState again and loading is false
        this.setState({
            myArray: tmp,
            loading: false,
        })
    } else { //there is no need to loading because not much elements need to be modified

        const tmp = [...this.state.myArray]; //copy the array
        for(let i=0; i<howManyElementsToEdit; i++) {
            tmp[i] += 1;
        }

        this.setState({
            myArray: tmp,
        })

    }   
}
```

But as you can guess it doesn't work, because probably react "merges" these 
2 setStates (when howManyElementsToEdit > 50) and that's why i don't see any loading
when i'm displaying this.state.loading in render.

Does anyone know how can i achieve my goal?

Comment: Why -1 ? I don't get it.

Comment: -2 ? ... ehh, why? i just want to do loading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React native only has a single js thread, so performing expensive calculations will clog up your app (you won't be able to interact with it).

That being said, if your loading time is significant enough to display the spinner, you should probably do that asynchronously, and not right after setState() (if it's fast enough, then you probably don't need a spinner to show up for 100ms).

When you call setState() and then do a bunch of work, the component will not re-render before that work is done, so two setState()-s is not the issue here. It wouldn't work even if you had only one.

Lucky for you, react-native's `ActivityIndicator` component's animation runs on native UI thread, so it isn't affected by the js thread performing expensive work. So, what you can do is delay the work a little bit to allow for the setState() to take effect. Here's the code:

```
this.setState({
  loading: true,
})
setTimeout(() => {
  const tmp = [...this.state.myArray]; //copy the array
  for(let i=0; i<howManyElementsToEdit; i++) {
    tmp[i] += 1;
  }

  this.setState({
    myArray: tmp,
    loading: false,
  });
}
```

`setTimeout` will move the expensive work to the back of the "queue", so your setState() will re-render the component first, and the expensive work will start afterwards. Beware, that this will still clog up the js thread (e.g you won't be able to navigate back until the work is done), but if you display `<ActivityIndicator />` whenever `loading` is `true`, it will spin without interruption.

Comment: omg, thank you. I know it should not happen, but there is one case in the whole project when the situation like this may take place (or when there is really a lot of data).